# change fitted line colour in nlme() trellis plot?

Tags: r, lattice, nlme

I am trying to use a grouped data to fit and then plot 
plot(augPred(fit)). However, I would like to change the line color as it is the similar color of the points. Is there a way to make the lines in a different color? Also, I would like to remove the data points in the plot, just leaving the two fitted lines so it would be easy to compare them. In the figure attached, I would like to remove data points and change the fitted lines color.

Thanks very much for any help. Ravi[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `plot.augPred` function in **nlme** is based on `xyplot` in the **lattice** package(see the help page for `plot.augPred` for more info), so you would have to delve into that package a bit more to see what you can add to change the plot.  There is a fair amount of info out there once you start looking, see [this link](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block16_colorsLatticeQualitative.html) and the help page of `xyplot` and `panel.xyplot` as possible starting places.

If it was me and I wanted to make a bunch of changes to the defaults, I'd probably just use the output from the `augPred` object and create a plot from scratch.  But you can certainly control the plot settings via the `par.settings` argument from `xyplot`.

Here is an example, using the `plot.augPred` help page example.  Consider including a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the future.

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- lme(Orthodont)
plot(augPred(fm1, level = 0:1, length.out = 2))
```

[image]

You can control colors line widths with `superpose.line` and `plot.symbol` to control the symbols.  If you want to get rid of the symbols all together you can set `pch` to `NA`.

```
plot(augPred(fm1, length.out = 2, level = c(0,1)),
    par.settings = list(superpose.line = list(col = c("red", "blue"), lwd = 2),
                    plot.symbol = list(pch = NA)))
```

[image]

Notice this failed to change the legend output, though, and so still needs some work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I am trying to change the legend colors as well by using 'key' or using list function but it does not work. It is logical values, TRUE or FALSE but it do not show any effect on the plot.

Comment: @Ravi Yeah, I didn't really find anything that worked on the legend, either, but I don't know **lattice** very well.  A compromise might be to leave the colors as is but increase the line width.  That along with removing the points may make the lines clear enough for what you want.

Comment: I partially achieved it. Though I count not change the legend, I removed it and added text in different colors suited to fitted line colors. So, half-success.

Comment: @Ravi Glad you figured something out.  Consider either marking this answer with the check mark or putting in your own answer and checking it so your question will be marked as [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).